# PowerCLI - How to run remote script on multiple host simultaneously

Tags: powershell

I have a great amount of Windows servers to maintain.

The script works fine, however, it has to wait for the output to continue to the next host. Because I have too many servers, and the commands runs in sequence, it take several minutes to finish. I would like to loop through all servers in parallel, without needing to wait for a response from each host.

In summary, I would like to optimize this script to run the above code simultaneously on multiple servers.

Here is my script:

```
Connect-VIServer "XXXXXXXXX" -User "XXXXX\user" -Password "P@ssword123!"

$vmName = "XXXXX"

Try{

   $vm = Get-VM -Name $vmName -ErrorAction Stop

   switch($vm.PowerState){

   'poweredon' {

  Shutdown-VMGuest -VM $vm -Confirm:$false

   while($vm.PowerState -eq 'PoweredOn'){

  sleep 5

   $vm = Get-VM -Name $vmName

   }

   }

   Default {

   Write-Host "VM '$($vmName)' is not powered on!"

   }

   }

   Write-Host "$($vmName) has shutdown. It should be ready for configuration."

}

Catch{

   Write-Host "VM '$($vmName)' not found!"

}

Start-Sleep 45

$snapshotName = "Pre_Upgrade_snapshot " + "$((Get-Date).ToString())"

$description = "Pre_Upgrade_snapshot " + "$((Get-Date).ToString())"

New-Snapshot -Name $snapshotName -VM $vmName -Description $description -Memory:$false -Quiesce:$true

Start-Sleep 45

$vm = Start-VM -VM $vmName -Confirm:$false

Start-Sleep 45

do {
  Start-Sleep 5
  $vm.ExtensionData.UpdateViewData('Guest')
}
while(-not $vm.EXtensionData.Guest.guestOperationsReady)

Write-Host "Power on VM on $($vmName)" -BackgroundColor Cyan

Start-Sleep 45

    #Update Template Local Account to Run Script
    $updateTempUser = "XXXXX"
    $updateTempPass = ConvertTo-SecureString 'XXXXXX' -AsPlainText -Force

$HashArguments = @{
    VM = $vmName
    ScriptText = "C:\InplaceUpgrade\setup.ps1"
    GuestUser = $updateTempUser
    GuestPassword = $updateTempPass
    ScriptType = "Powershell"
    ErrorAction = "Stop"
  }

Invoke-VMScriptWrapper -VMScriptParams $HashArguments
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
# Import our CSV file of VirtualMachine hostnames.
$CSV = import-csv "Hosts.csv"

# Output path to store the error log.
$OutputPath = ""

#Credentials that will run ConnectViServer
$ViServerUsername = "xxxx\user"
$ViServerPassword = "xxxxxxxxx"

$ScriptBlock = {
  param (
    $Hostname,
    $Username,
    $Pass
  )
  
  # Any commands that create data in Write-Output will mess up the list of return variables, either:
  # Pipe output into Out-Null to discard it.
  Connect-VIServer $hostname -User $Username -Password $Pass | Out-Null
  # OR save output to a variable and include in the return list.
  $VariableYouWantToReturn = Connect-VIServer $hostname -User $Username -Password $Pass

  #...(All your other code you need to be run)

  # The $Error variable contains a list of errors that occurred during the run.
  # By returning it, we get the opportunity to revise what went wrong in the job.
  return $Error, $VariableYouWantToReturn, $AnotherVariableYouWantToReturn
}

# Grab all remaining jobs from the last time this script was run, stop and remove them.
# If you don't do this then it will mess up your results for each session as they aren't removed.
# We identify the relevant jobs by the JobName parameter set with Invoke-Command or Start-Job.
Get-Job -Name "*-VM-Maint-Job" | Stop-Job
Get-Job -Name "*-VM-Maint-Job" | Remove-Job

# Iterate through each entry in the Hosts.csv and create a job for each one.
foreach ($entry in $CSV) {

  # The job runs the scriptblock on the remote machine using Invoke-Command.
  # Or runs each job in parallel locally using Start-Job.

  # Invoke-Command for remote execution.
  #Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Entry.Host -AsJob -ScriptBlock $ScriptBloc -ArgumentList @($entry, $ViServerUsername, $ViServerPassword) -JobName "$($Entry.Host)-VM-Maint-Job"
  # Start-Job for local execution.
  Start-Job -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -ArgumentList @($entry, $ViServerUsername, $ViServerPassword) -Name "$($Entry.Host)--VM-Maint-Job"
}

# Wait here until all jobs are complete.
$Jobs = Get-Job -Name "*-VM-Maint-Job" | Wait-Job

# Holds the results.
$ResultTable = @()

# Grab the results of each job and format them into a nice table.
Foreach ($JobResult in $Jobs) {
  $Results = Receive-Job -Job $JobResult
  # $Results[0] is the error array returned by the job.
  # $Results[1] is $VariableYouWantToReturn
  # $Results[2] is $AnotherVariableYouWantToReturn
  # If there's any chance that your return variables might be null,then prefix them with [string] like below, otherwise Export-CSV will throw an error trying to export an empty variable.

  # Store the results in a hash table, these define the headings of our output CSV file.
  $ResultTable += [ordered]@{
    JobName                        = $JobResult.Name;
    ErrorMessages                  = $Results[0] -Join " | ";
    VariableYouWantToReturn        = [string]$Results[1];
    AnotherVariableYouWantToReturn = [string]$Results[2];
    DateTime                       = $JobResult.PSBeginTime
  }

  # Print each error found to the console.
  Foreach ($Err in $Results[0]) {
    Write-Error "Failed job for $($JobResult.Name). Error Message: $($Err.ErrorDetails_Message)" -ErrorAction Continue
  }
}

# Export any errors and accompanying returns to a CSV file.
$ResultTable | Export-CSV -Path ($OutputPath + "Results.csv")
```

This script runs the contents of `$ScriptBlock` locally for each host listed in a CSV file called `Hosts.csv` which has one header called `host` and that column is a list of each computer Hostname or IP Address.
You should modify the contents of `$ScriptBlock` to add additional code you need to run, be mindful of how the parameters work and how they are passed through using `Invoke-Command` or `Start-Job`, I've included your `Connect-VIServer` commandlet as an example.

`Start-Job` is used to run each job in parallel on the local computer. It will return a Job object which is awaited on by Wait-Job at the very end. The script will run all the jobs in parallel and then wait until each one is complete.

You might want to [read up on how jobs work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_jobs?view=powershell-7.3) and how to get their results, which will be useful for troubleshooting.

At the end of `$ScriptBlock` is a `return` statement. Variables included in the return statement can be viewed in the results of the completed jobs, any data not returned is discarded, including exceptions which is why I've included the $Error variable, this will return a list of any errors generated by the remote job while it ran.

I've included a method of gathering results from jobs, printing any errors to the console and saving the list to a CSV file which is useful when troubleshooting jobs is unusual compared to normal scripts.

Comment: @Arbelac Ah sorry, I misunderstood your use-case. If you don't need to run remote jobs then you can just swap out `Invoke-Command` for `Start-Job`, I've modified my answer for you.

Comment: @Arbelac sorry, I've now fixed that error try the new code please.

Comment: @Arbelac I can't see that image

Comment: @Arbelac it looks like your commands inside the Scriptblock need some kind of user input and are waiting for it. You'll need to modify any code you include there to be completely automatic, passing any required info to the commands ahead of time. If you run the script once, you might be able to do `Get-Job -name "*-VM-Maint-Job" | Receive-Job` or `$Jobs[0] | Receive-Job` after it errors in order to find out what your script is waiting for.

Comment: I've edited the last few lines for exporting errors, please try now. I think there are no errors being returned so `$ResultTable` would be empty, it might be worth checking inside that variable to be sure. Not 100% sure though because Export-CSV should be fine even with an empty list.

Comment: I am assuming , it may be an issue related to the Result[0]  variable.  Because , There is VMWare Vcentrer IP , Username information inside variable. Actually NOT error message. https://imgur.com/a/oGTwGOH

Comment: Ah I see, I misunderstood how the jobs build and return a list of outputs. Essentially, every single thing sent to Write-Output becomes an entry in the returns list, while I was expecting errors to always be the first entry, if any of your commands generate output first they will take its place. I'll think about how to improve that later, for now I recommend you pipe any commands that produce an output that you don't need into `| Out-Null` to discard it, any that you want to see the output for, save to a variable and include in the returns list.

Comment: @Arbelac I've re-worked the whole returns processing section now, you'll still need to pipe any outputs from commands into Write-Null or save them to variables to prevent the return list being messed up. Returning empty variables won't cause it to error while exporting anymore, hope this example works for you.